# Sound with animation in android

Tags: android, android-animation

Hi I am making a slide show.images slide automatically in slide show these images are user selected images stored in array.now i want to plat user selected audio along with animation.but i don't know how to do this.the images animation is working fine but canot play sound at background.here is my code

```
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

            // Create runnable for posting
            final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                        AnimateandSlideShow();
                             }
            };

           // mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateResults, 300);
            int delay =300; // delay for 1 sec.

            int period = 9000; // repeat every 4 sec.

            Timer timer = new Timer();

            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {


            public void run() {

                 mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

            }

            }, delay, period);

            ////////end animation//////////////////
```

here is the animatedslideshow function:

```
 private void AnimateandSlideShow() {
         // playsound();
         //  sound =new AnimationSound(SlideShow.this,uriaudio);
         //  sound.startsound();

           iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.anim_view);

          iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(allimgs.get(count%allimgs.size()).toString()));

          count++;
           anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SlideShow.this, R.anim.fade_in);

           // load your desire animation.
            iv.startAnimation(anim);

    }
```

and playsound:

```
private void playsound()
      {
          MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(SlideShow.this, uriaudio); 
            player.setLooping(false); // Set looping 
            player.setVolume(100,100); 
            player.start(); 

      }
```

i don't know where to put the playsound function in handler so that audio starts with animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play sound and stop it in AnimationListener's method as shown here:

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(SlideShow.this, uriaudio); 
player.setLooping(false); // Set looping 
player.setVolume(100,100); 
final int mPlayerLength = 0;

anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        player.seekTo(mPlayerLength);
        player.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
         if(player.isPlaying()){
            player.stop();
            mPlayerLength = player.getCurrentPosition();
        }
    }
};
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**

Yes, `final` modifier will not let you change it later. Sorry for that. I didn't run the code. Here is the alternate: You can implement `AnimationListener` in your activity. So you will not need to keep the variable as final to access it in methods:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener{

    int mPlayerLength = 0;  //global variable

    anim.setAnimationListener(this);       

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        player.seekTo(mPlayerLength);
        player.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(player.isPlaying()){
            player.stop();
            mPlayerLength = player.getCurrentPosition();
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this is clear and solves issue :)

Comment: Thanks your code helped me .but it starts sound with each image.i want to play sound through the animation.mean want to play single track till the end of animation.

Comment: @user3719290 Then you can pause and start from last position as shown in edited answer. try that.

Comment: it gives error with the final keyword .we are using final so then we cant change it in  mPlayerLength = player.getCurrentPosition();  :(

Comment: still facing sound issue :'(

Comment: @user3719290 what kind of issue now??

Comment: it play the single song in chunks,with each image.i guess it has some delay issue or something.i am using the animatedslide show funtion(which has animation listner inside it) in handler with dealy=300 and period =900.

Comment: final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {                 public void run() {
          AnimateandSlideShow();} }; 
           // mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateResults, 100);
          int delay =300; // delay for 1 sec.
             int period =900; // repeat every 4 sec.
             Timer timer = new Timer();             
             timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {              
             public void run() {              
               mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);               
             }
             }, delay, period);