# animation to hide button

Tags: android, animation, button

hey guys i have this code will hide a button and then re display it what i want is to hide it without re displaying it  here is the code that i use:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
   <alpha
   android:fromAlpha="1.0"
   android:toAlpha="0.1"
   android:duration="500"
   android:repeatCount="1"
   android:repeatMode="reverse" />
   </set>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
   <alpha
       android:fromAlpha="1.0"
       android:toAlpha="0.1"
       android:duration="500"
       android:repeatCount="0"
       android:fillAfter="true"
   />
</set>
```

This will cause the animation to hide button, and not repeat in reverse mode to show it again.

Read [repeatMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setRepeatMode%28int%29) and [repeatCount](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setRepeatCount%28int%29) for clearing doubt and better understanding.

Hope this helps.

Comment: :( no its not going like what i want is to totally disappear this also make the button visible again

Comment: @Dexter90 Make sure you have not used [setFillAfter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter%28boolean%29)(true).

Comment: @dexter do you want to fade out then the btn should be there??

Comment: @Dhruti no i am not using this method should i used

Comment: @Toppers there is four button in my activity what i am doing is whenever i click on a button the three other button should be hided and then go to another activity that what i am trying to do :)

Comment: Yes. `android:fillAfter="true"`. Add this line in xml. @Dexter90

Comment: @Dhruti sorry for my question but i am really new to android in which XML file in the animation file ?

Comment: @Dhruti one more question can we have a method to let some action to wait before another action

Comment: You mean something like [animation listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)? @Dexter90

Comment: @Dhruti i implement animation listener and when animation start i started another animation i want when the other animation finish to start another activity i will mention the code in another comment to let you understand more

Comment: @Dhruti animTranslate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
   
   
   public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
             
    windows_phone.startAnimation(Hide);
    C_sharp.startAnimation(Hide);
             Website.startAnimation(Hide);
             
       try {
           startActivity(new Intent("com.f5.Android_page")); 

     }

     catch (Exception ex) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.toString(),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     } 
             
   }

Comment: put startAnimation code in `onAnimationEnd` instead of `onAnimationStart` @Dexter90 .

Comment: @Dexter90 I guess you would have to post a new question and put whole code their maintaining what you need to do.

Comment: And see [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861323/sound-with-animation-in-android/24861397#24861397) if that solves your issue. @Dexter90

Comment: @Dhruti did that happen to you ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624137/exception-when-trying-to-put-in-my-activity-any-type-of-edittext

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fade out and leave the visibility as visible to button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  
       <alpha android:fromAlpha="1" android:toAlpha="0"           
          android:duration="@*android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />
  </set>
```

and then add this to your button

```
      Animation slide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.fadeout); //the above transition
     yourBtn.startAnimation(slide);
```

Comment: yup change the duration .... you can add your own or refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.integer.html and FYI if you want to reverse the animation i.e fade in then just change android:fromAlpha="0"  and android:toAlpha="0".....simple

Comment: Oh thanks very much i will check it i would like to hear your point of view in the previous answer in the comment i mentioned a problem can you help me with that ?

Comment: @dexture just to confirm...it seems that you want wait to execute another action until your animation finish...right??

Comment: yeah exactly that what i want :D

Comment: i am trying to put another question but they told me every 90 min why this rule?

Comment: Dexter90  @Dhruti solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861323/sound-with-animation-in-android/24861397#24861397 is right.....you can add your method in onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)  it will be called once your animation will finish..