# Exception when trying to put in my activity any type of editText

Tags: android, exception

```
 `  Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V
    Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log`
```

this exception is raised during any implementation of any type of EditText can you help me guys ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in adding an edit text in eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592647/error-in-adding-an-edit-text-in-eclipse) Just change the rendering target from API-20 (4.4W) to API-19

Comment: @reVerse there is no 19 only 20 ?

Comment: Did you download any SDK-Platform prior to API-Level 20 via the SDK-Manager?

Comment: i try the solution given by deleting it now my eclipse is never running....

Comment: Then you should do it. API-Level 20 represent Android Wear and this version doesn't support `EditTexts`since it's not running on phones

Comment: @reVerse [2014-09-02 16:16:30 - F5] Unable to resolve target 'android-20'
[2014-09-02 16:16:40 - F5] Unable to resolve target 'android-20'
[2014-09-02 16:16:59 - F5] Unable to resolve target 'android-20'

Comment: Yeah you just uninstalled android-20 that's why this error occurs. Download Android 4.4 and set the target to android-19

Comment: @reVerse i am downloading android api 19 i will have the same problem or the problem will be solved ?

Comment: It should be, you can download api 20 again as well. But you need api 19 to render the layout correctly.

Comment: @reVerse when i finish downloading the 19 api i will then download the api 20 again

Comment: @reVerse vot up my question pls

Comment: @reVerse when i download it the error still exsist